How do blocking operations in Spring MVC with WebClient work?
I have a problem understanding the following scenario, therefore seeking for clarification.
I have a Spring Boot application using Web MVC.
I'm using the following dependencies:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

I know that adding both spring-boot-starter-web and spring-boot-starter-webflux modules in auto-configures Spring MVC over Spring WebFlux, explained here.
The app is providing a REST controller, such as:
@RestController
public class EmployeeRestController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService service;
    
    @GetMapping("/api/employee/get/{id}")
    public Employee getEmployee(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        return service.fetchEmployeeData(id);
    }
}

The getEmployee method uses the EmployeeService, which then should communicate with a third party API through Spring's Reactive WebClient (because RestTemplate is deprecated). The service looks like this:
@Service
public class EmployeeService {

    private final WebClient webClient;

    public EmployeeService(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
        this.webClient = webClientBuilder.baseUrl("http://mydatasource.com/employees").build();
    }

    public Employee fetchEmployeeData(int id) {
        Employee result = this.webClient
            .get()
            .url(id)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Employee.class)
            .block();

        // do other service-related stuff here

        return result;
    }
}

You might have already noticed the block-operation, which should usually not be used in Reactive programming to not block threads/application.
I came to the assumption, that it wouldn't matter using non-blocking mechanisms as Spring Web MVC runs on a blocking stack, following a one thread per request pattern. Because of this, the block-operation would only block the assigned thread of the ongoing request - correct? (This is backed with a great visualization in section 1 of this blog.)
Therefore my question: Is my understanding/assumption correct? If so, how could I easily prove it?

No it would block the thread from the pool used by the WebClient which uses a reactive library. So it will actually block 2 threads. Also can we stop calling RestTemplate deprecated as it isn't it is in maintenance mode. Instead of WebClient there is now also a RestClient which is basically the replacement for RestTemplate. There is also nothing preventing you from returning Mono<Employee> from your controller, this will be handled by Spring MVC for you and will use the async features of the servlet API.

So this means, 2 blocked threads within one request then? The other requests should be fine, though?
Thank you for the tip regarding RestClient, did not know about this.

Well if there are too many threads blocked nothing will happen any more, the CPU is then busy checking the blocked threads on which can continue. So if the other requests are fine, remains to be seen. I would just return a Mono<Employee> and leverage the async servlet API.
